# Incomplete Apache logging

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I have a problem with Apache running on a Linux server. This error `undefined index on PHP`, for example.

The problem is that my Apache server doesn't log entire error messages.
Some lines from the `error.log` file:

```
[Thu Nov 29 05:29:06 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  lin
[Thu Nov 29 05:29:06 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: 9
[Thu Nov 29 05:31:30 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:      link in /var/www/html/sit
[Thu Nov 29 06:01:18 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  link in /var
[Thu Nov 29 06:06:09 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined
[Thu Nov 29 06:06:15 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:
[Thu Nov 29 06:13:04 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PH
[Thu Nov 29 07:14:16 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undef
[Thu Nov 29 07:32:16 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  link in /var/www/ht
[Thu Nov 29 07:34:26 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  link
[Thu Nov 29 07:34:30 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  link in /var/www/html/site.com/
[Thu Nov 29 07:41:10 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Und
[Thu Nov 29 07:41:11 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Und
[Thu Nov 29 07:41:12 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Und
[Thu Nov 29 08:14:20 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undef
[Thu Nov 29 12:36:54 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  li
[Thu Nov 29 12:37:04 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Unde
[Thu Nov 29 12:46:52 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  link in /var/www/htm
[Thu Nov 29 13:00:33 2012] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: line 35
[Thu Nov 29 13:10:55 2012] [error] [client XXX.XX.XX.XX] File does not exist: /var/www/h
```

Some lines are incomplete and truncate the error message.

Anyone know Why Apache is saving incomplete error messages?

Comment: Does Apache write directly to the files or is there a logging service (such as rsyslog or syslog-ng) in between?  Does it happen to your access logs as well?

Comment: I think that write directly (I have some Apache customlogs, but don't register with other software). Access log not affected, this error only affect error log.

Answer (score 0):

I would first make sure that your system is in good condition. To be specific, make sure that you have enough ram/swap and that your hard disk is not full. If a VPS is being used, make sure that hard disk is not full at the host level as well.

Another place to check out is for any other logs. Are any other system/services logs suffering the same problem? Or is it just apache? Be sure to check out messages log from the OS.

Comment: I have more than 10GB of free space. Also, 1GB free RAM available. Only Apache affected by this strange problem.